# Custom SLF4J logger with new line at the end

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I have the following class which I have all my classes that need a logger to extend it:

```
public abstract class GeneralLogger {

    final public Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

}
```

... and a sample class that extends it

```
class MyClass extends GeneralLogger {

    public void myMethod() {
            // some usage of the logger
            logger.info("Hi, I am a logger at {}", new Date().toString());
    }

}
```

This works fine but I need the logs to be separated by new line character for readability.
I know I can put a `System.lineSeparator()` at the end, but the problem is, I have so many implementations of the `logger` object. Also, I wouldn't want to keep adding the line separator for each log that I write.

So I was wondering if there is some way I can create a custom logger that I can replace the current one.

Comment: add extra new line to the pattern in the configuration of the logging library you are using. ex: log4j.properties / log4j.xml "\n"
see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout

Comment: Hahaha. That was really easy. I couldn't think of that. Thanks